# PHP Download file from a link that automatically downloads a file

Tags: php, file, url, download

I'm making a website where you can download multiple files at once as a zip file by selecting what files you want to download. And to download the files I want to use an external URL. And all that works if I'm using a URL that doesn't automatically download the file to the users PC when a user visits that page an example of that kind of URL would be https://example.com/picturetodownload/picture.png

But if I wanted to download a file from an URL that automatically downloads the file when a user visits that URL all I get is a file named "download_version=364651" for example. An example of a URL like this would be: https://example.com/thingtodownload/download?version=364651

This is my current code:

```
if(isset($_POST['files'])) {
$error = ""; //error holder
if(isset($_POST['createzip'])) {
    $post = $_POST; 
    $tmpFile = tempnam('tmp/', '');
    if(extension_loaded('zip')) { 
    // Checking ZIP extension is available
    if(isset($post['files']) and count($post['files']) > 0) { 
    // Checking files are selected
    $zip = new ZipArchive(); // Load zip library 
    if($zip->open($tmpFile, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) { 
        // Opening zip file to load files
        $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
    }
    foreach($post['files'] as $file) { 
        $context = stream_context_create(
            array(
                "http" => array(
                    "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
                )
            )
        );
        $fileContent = file_get_contents($file, false, $context);

        if ($zip->addFromString(basename($file), $fileContent)!==TRUE) {
            echo "DOESN'T WORK";
            die();
        }
        //echo "WORKS"; This part of the code seems to be working.
        //die;
    }
    $zip->close();
    if(file_exists($tmpFile)) {
        // push to download the zip
        header('Content-type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.zip');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmpFile));
        readfile($tmpFile);
        // remove zip file is exists in temp path
        unlink($tmpFile);
    } else {
        exit("Error finding file.");
    }
}
else
$error .= "* Please select file to zip ";
}
else
$error .= "* You dont have ZIP extension";
}
}
```

Thanks,
Nimetu.

Comment: Well you're using $file as the name of the file in your zip file. basename($file) contains the end of the URL you used to fetch the data, so obviously if you use that you won't end up with a useful / conventional filename. The files you're downloading should have a filename included in the content-disposition header of the response (just like in the response you're preparing in order to serve the zip file), so you could try getting the filename from that and using it instead.